# tuple of void member functions

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, function-pointers

I'm attempting to create a tuple which contains a pointer to a void member function, but I'm having trouble making it work. 
here's my code:

```
class A
{
    void dostuff(){ cout<<" doing stuff "}
};

class B
{
    A* aobj;
    typedef vector<vector<tuple<int,int,void(A::*)()>>> sequence;

    sequence Sequence;

    void getinfo(int n1, int n2, void(A::*func)())
    {
        Sequence.resize(1);
        Sequence[0].push_back(make_tuple(n1,n2,(aobj->*func)()))//<--ERROR HERE
    };
};
```

it's giving me the error "invalid use of void expression."
I also tried to simplify the function to :

```
void getinfo(void(A::*func)())
{
    make_tuple((aobj->*func)());
}
```

and it still gives me the same error.

Comment: `(aobj->*func)()` calls the method, which returns nothing; you are trying to place that nothing into the tuple. If you want to place the member pointer itself, that would be `make_tuple(n1,n2,func)`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, I think that deserves to be converted to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Igor Tandetnik pointed out, (aobj->*func)() was calling the method and returning void to the make_tuple() function. To pass a member pointer, it should instead be make_tuple(n1,n2,func).